# Proxy Pass to External Server (NGINX to Azure Traffic Manager)

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, code-injection

I'm trying to set up a MITM Proxy to inject JS scripts during transit using NGINX in front of a web app sitting behind an Azure Traffic Manager. I need some assistance with configuring this correctly (see below for an example of what I'm trying to achieve).

```
Client
  |
  |
  |
NGINX (Inject Javascript)
  |
  |
  |
Azure Traffic Manager
  |
  |
  |
Web App
```

There is no dodgy business here, I just need to manipulate a feature in a web app, which I do not have back-end access for, passing in a JS script will allow me to do this.

I've tried the code block listed below, with a **C Name** pointing to the NGINX Server. Normally the Traffic Manager requires the **C Name** to be pointing to it to resolve properly. With the NGINX config I have now, I am able to reach the traffic manager, however, it resolves with a **404 Web Site not found**.

This is a snippet of my `default` file within `site-confs`

```sh
...

server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

        server_name mysubdomain.domain.com.au;

        include /config/nginx/proxy-confs/*.subfolder.conf;
        include /config/nginx/ssl.conf;

        location / {
                sub_filter </head>
                        '</head><script language="javascript" src="link.tomydomain.com/custom-script.js"></script>';
                sub_filter_once on;
                resolver 8.8.8.8;
                proxy_pass http://azure.trafficmanager.net;
                proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header Destination http://gluh.trafficmanager.net;
        }
}

...
```

Looking at my `access.log` file I see the following logged.

```sh
...
121.xxx.xx.xxx - - [13/Jun/2019:21:11:57 +1000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 404 1161 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36"
121.xxx.xx.xxx - - [13/Jun/2019:21:11:57 +1000] "GET /link.tomydomain.com/custom-script.js HTTP/2.0" 499 0 "https://mysubdomain.domain.com.au/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36"
...
```

My expected result is that the HTTP/HTTPS traffic transparently passes through the proxy with the script tags attached to the `<head> ... </head>` of the document. What am I missing here, does Azure Traffic Manager require specific information it to route properly?

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up sorting this out by culling headers, see below for reference. I also switched $proxy_host to $host which azure traffic manager required for routing.

```
location / {
                sub_filter </head>
                        '</head><script language="javascript" src="link.tomydomain.com/custom-script.js"></script>';
                sub_filter_once on;
                resolver 8.8.8.8;
                proxy_pass http://azure.trafficmanager.net;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
```